# Can't change Column color at runtime if its default color is "Transparent"

Tags: colors, powerbuilder, datawindow

I use the following code to change the color of particular columns when I open the datewindow up for editing:

```
dw_1.object.description.Background.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
```

This works great as long as the default background color was not "Transparent" in the painter.
If it starts out transparent, this code does nothing.

How can I have the column be transparent, but change it to white and then back again?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the `background.mode` property to `0` to remove the transparency and take the `background.color` into account.

The manual says in the `Background.property DataWindow object property` entry:

> Transparent background
>   If Background.Mode is transparent (1), Background.Color is ignored.

Comment: this is the method I wound up using.  If the default color is transparent, in code you will have to first set the mode to 0, and then you are free to change the color.  Setting Mode to 1 will put it back to transparent.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Set up your column backcolor to white (for example) and set its backcolor **expression** to `553648127`.

After that you may change it with `Modify`

```
// To white
dw_1.Modify("description.Background.Color='16777215~t16777215'")
// To transparent
dw_1.Modify("description.Background.Color='16777215~t553648127'")
```

May be `dw_1.SetRedraw(true)` will be needed.

You may also create hidden column (`desc_bc` for example), set its name into expression for backcolor, and change its value instead of calling Modify.